# Going yesterday from date of string

Tags: php, date, php-carbon

I have a string of date with format '2016/10/10'. I am trying to make a function to bring it yesterday but I want it to work with every yesterday, and with doing it manually, after a while I realised that it got pretty complicated and failing to detect for example February 29.

What is the best practice to bring it to a date in string to yesterday with the same format? I'm almost sure there must be an automated way.

```
 $date = '2016/10/10';
 $newDate = goYesterday($date);
```

p.s.: It is not  a timestamp so I though I should stay away from Carbon. I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `strtotime`, which gets a "general string" as the first parameter, and the second parameter is the relative date.

```
$date = '2016/10/10';
$newDate = date('Y/m/d', strtotime('yesterday', strtotime($date)));
echo $newDate;
```

> Note that I already used the `date` function to format.

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks a lot

Comment: hi man. I have a quick question. How about if i want to subtract 7 days rather than simply writing yesterday. That'd be useful for both me and someone else if you can a little extend other use cases. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Did you try to use `-7 day` instead of `yesterday` ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Better to use object oriented way

```
$date = '2016/10/10';
$dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $date);
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$dateObj->sub($interval);
$newDate = $dateObj->format('Y/m/d');
```

Comment: Why is it better to use object oriented rather than procedural? You're making a claim and not basing it on anything.